# jquery resets border animation

Tags: jquery, border, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have a div with 1px solid border. and I want to give it a border color animation with jquery. Here is my code ;

```
//Products border motion
jQuery(".products-two").mouseenter(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).stop(true,true).animate({borderColor: '#999999'},400);
    }).mouseleave(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).stop(true,true).animate({borderColor: '#E6E6E6'}, 800);
    }
    );
```

I also import ui class from ;

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.js

My problem is;

When mouseleave function works, it removes the border first, then it changes the border color. And that doesn't give a smooth motion. What should I do?

UPDATE - I also changed motion time and now realized it's also happening when mouse enters. It removes the border first, then it adds the border and changes its color.

SOLUTION - Since I can not answer my questions I wanted share the solution for others who may interest.

I guess this is a bug about jquery ui class. Because when I use regular jquery library with default border properties it works. I skipped this ui method and used this as a temp solution.

```
//Products border motion
    jQuery(".products-two").mouseenter(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).stop().animate({borderTopColor:'#999999', borderBottomColor:'#999999',borderLeftColor:'#999999',borderRightColor:'#999999'},400);
    }).mouseleave(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).stop().animate({borderTopColor:'#E6E6E6', borderBottomColor:'#E6E6E6',borderLeftColor:'#E6E6E6',borderRightColor:'#E6E6E6'},400);
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [prevent the animation from queueing](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.2/Effects#Simultaneous_Animations).

```
jQuery(".products-two").mouseenter(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).stop(true,true).animate({borderColor: '#999999'},400);
    }).mouseleave(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).stop(true,true).animate({borderColor: '#E6E6E6', queue: false}, 800);
    }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I tried this code but its still the same. And I'm reading the documents you linked, still couldn't find a solution